# Gathering value from one table and using it in second query?

Tags: php, sql

Okay this is going to sound dumb, however having some difficulties on the best way of doing this; I'm trying to grab all the users that an account is following; then once I've grabbed all the users I'm following from the following table grab the user information for the users table. this is what I have so far but It's really messy and non working.

```
<?
$usr_id = '34';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM following WHERE usr_id = '$usr_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
// $following is the users that we are following.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $following = $row['following'];

$src = "SELECT * FROM usr_users WHERE username = '$following'";
$getfollowinginfo = mysql_query($src);

while ($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($getfollowinginfo)) { 

        echo $user['email'];

}}
?>
```

Comment: At what point does the code stop working?

Comment: @DiddleDot it only echos out one result. when there is 4 people I'm following.

Comment: You may want to use a `JOIN` here.  I'm not fluent enough in SQL to be more specific.

Comment: can you show your table structure

Comment: @urfusion uploaded :-)

Comment: Use a JOIN. What you're doing is wrong.

Comment: You're going to want another table to hold IDs if you want more than one person to be able to follow somebody at a time.

Comment: okay i changed the following column to display there ids instead of there usernames and it now works and i can collect any information from the usr_users table It now works thankyou for that suggestion. I don't know how to use a join statement aha sorry for the constant questions thankyou though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mention, a `JOIN` is much more appropriate here. Based on your example, [here is a simple SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/81362/1) showing how it works.

The most important part is targeting the `Following` table then `JOIN`ing to the `Users` table, like so:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM Following f
JOIN Users u on u.id=f.following
WHERE f.userId = 3 -- Can be any identifier for the user.
```

For small or simple datasets this is perfectly fine, but some may suggest you remove the `WHERE` clause and instead expand the JOIN condition, like so:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM Following f
JOIN Users u on u.id=f.following
    AND f.userId = 3 -- Can be any identifier for the user.
```

To integrate that into your code, it's as easy as this;

```
<?
    $usr_id = '34';

    $sql = "SELECT u.id, u.email FROM following f JOIN usr_users u on u.id=f.following AND f.usr_id = '$usr_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result )) {
        echo $user['email'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: very helpful and thank you for integrating it and  explaining how to use join it's really helpful and means I can use it in future projects. thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!